# Help with failing Grails test - domain methods not working?

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy

Given this service:

```
class AchievementsService {

    static transactional = true

    public void onEvent(String eventName, User user) {
        def event = Event.findByName(eventName)
        if (!event) {
            event = new Event(name: eventName, autoConfigured: true)
            event.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this test failing:

```
class AchievementsServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    AchievementsService service
    User user
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        service = new AchievementsService()
        user = new User(username:"marty",password: "password")
        mockDomain(User,[user])
    }

    void testThat_given_eventDoesNotExistWhenCallingOnEvent_that_eventIsCreated()
    {
         mockDomain Event       
         service.onEvent "MyEvent", user
         assert Event.count() == 1
    }
}
```

Fails as follows:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert Event.count() == 1
             |       |
             0       false
```

I must be missing a step either in my setup, or when calling my `.save()` method, but I can't see it.

Comment: Do you get any validation errors on event? Add this to your service to test: `if (!event.save()) { event.errors.each{println it} }`

Comment: Does it work if you run it as an integration test? You may need to remove the calls to `mockDomain` after converting it to an integration test

Comment: @David - thanks, I had a missing constraint in my model.  Convert this to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a validation failure, add this code to your service to print validation errors:

```
if (!event.save()) { 
  event.errors.each{println it} 
}
```